# Spring Security in a Stateless webapp?

Tags: spring, spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create-session stateless usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800855/create-session-stateless-usage)

Im just beginning experimenting on Spring Security, on version 3.1, and im wondering how to achieve authentication with a stateless webapp.

http-basic and digest come to mind, and i've tried them, but i dislike the inability to logout like the form authentication without closing the browser.

I currently have a working stateless webapp with form-based authentication using spring security (which makes it stateful by storing auth stuffs in session perhaps ?), and i wonder what are the strategies that i could research on to make spring security work without making use of http sessions ?

I realize that there's a `<http create-session="stateless" ..>`, but there must be something that needs more doing because the app stops working correctly after i tried that, by keep authenticating me when accessing protected resources.

Here's my config :

```
<http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless">
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
        login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
    <logout logout-url="/static/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/person/test/**" 
        access="isAuthenticated() and principal.username=='albertkam'"
    />
    <intercept-url pattern="/person/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_NORMAL')"/>

    <remember-me
        key="spitterKey"
        token-validity-seconds="2419200"/>
</http>
```

**With** `create-session="stateless"` :

1. accessing *http://myhost:8080/mycontext/person/blah*
2. goes to login page
3. returns to homepage url *http://myhost:8080/mycontext* after logging in (i expect it returns to the protected resource)

**Without** `create-session="stateless"`, which defaults to *ifRequired* (stateful) :

1. accessing *http://myhost:8080/mycontext/person/blah*
2. goes to login page
3. returns to the protected url *http://myhost:8080/mycontext/person/ blah* after logging in (this is correct behaviour , but stateful)

Comment: It's been answered in this [topic][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800855/create-session-stateless-usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use `always-use-default-target="false"` on `<form-login>`to prevent going to default page after successful login.

Comment: Hi, i tried your suggestion, but it still goes to the homepage with the stateless. I think it's not the the problem, since without the stateless attribute value, the flow works fine.

Comment: Oh am sorry to know that, I thought always-use-default-target="false" should work in case of stateless too.