# How to remove JSESSIONID from cookies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot,Spring MVC and Spring Security. I added JWT authorization so i need to make my application Session Stateless, so i added corresponding parameter to my Security Config:

```
 http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

But when I make any request to my app i get JSESSIONID as cookie. I tried to solve the problem by adding this code to my jwt filter:

```
    Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
    if(cookies!=null)
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
            httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookies[i]);
        }
```

But it did not help, so how to finally remove it ??

My full security code:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/user/get/**").hasRole(Role.BOT.toString()).antMatchers("/", "/login**","/callback/", "/webjars/**", "/error**")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();


  http.apply(new JwtFilterConfiguer(provider));



}
```

Comment: No. Im making REST

Comment: Are you sure that your configuration is used? Do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, I use Spring Boot, my security configuration is used for sure.

Comment: I have asked a similar question already, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573539/spring-adds-a-jsessionid-despite-stateless-session-management

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring adds a JSESSIONID despite stateless session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573539/spring-adds-a-jsessionid-despite-stateless-session-management)

Comment: @ggff have you fix this issue? facing same issue and no clue till now.

Answer (score 1):

The MaxAge of -1 signals that you want the cookie to persist for the duration of the session. You want to set MaxAge to 0 instead.

From the [API documentation][1]:

> A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.

please you can follow this link also 'https://www.baeldung.com/java-servlet-cookies-session'

Comment: I have cookie.setMaxAge(0);